# javascript load response of XMLHttpRequest after server answer

Tags: javascript, http

i'm stuck on an issue i could not find an answer to.

i have the following code:

```
function LanguageClicked(language_clicked){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "", false /* async */);
    request.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", language_clicked);
    request.send();

    ----HERE SHOLUD BE THE CODE FOR CHANGING THE WEB PAGE TO THE SERVER 
    RESPONSE----
}
```

how can i do that? i want to change the current page to the server response page.

Comment: We need more information.

Comment: sync requests are boring… ;)

Comment: i want that after the user pressed on a language - i will change the web page to the new page - the one returned from the server - the request.responseText , but without creating new request to server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think about this ?

```js
function LanguageClicked(language_clicked) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // Here we go on the new page
      window.location = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  request.open("GET", "", false /* async */ );
  request.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", language_clicked);
  request.send();
}
```

Comment: that is what i initially did , but the problem is that the window.location create another GET request without the modified header.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, can you make an example (in pseudo-code) ?

Comment: of course:

1. display initial page where the user choose language
2. after language clicked
3. send the server the requested language
4. the server response with the corresponding html file
5. load that page on client side without creating another GET request to server

Comment: change the window.location by document.body = xhttp.responseText; ? A bit greedy..

Comment: What's the problem ? Can you describe the file send by the server in the `xhttp.responseText` ?

Comment: yes - the file is html page returned as string.
i want to change the page to the new page returned from server without having the need to issue a new request - i want to use the server response to load the new page.

Comment: I think you have to load a part of the page not the full page cause you probably can't

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
function LanguageClicked(language_clicked) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // Here we go on the new page
      document.write(xhttp.responseText);
    }
  };
  request.open("GET", "", false /* async */ );
  request.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", language_clicked);
  request.send();
}
```

Comment: that just write over and over on same page